# How to show only table rows that have content in a Table View in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

This probably seems like an easy question, but I can't seem to find it.  The default behavior of the Table View seems to be to populate blank table cell rows to fill the entire screen even if you have only a few rows populated with labels.

I would like to only show rows that have labels and not when they are blank.  So for example if my Table View had only 5 labels, I would like to show only those 5 and not show rows to fill up the screen.

How do I accomplish this in the Storyboard attributes window if possible of via code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the footer view on the table and it will accomplish what you want.

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```